# How do i run my M-file serially while changing a particular variable?

Tags: matlab

I want to carry out a sensitivity study for my Matlab script. The script has 3 different variables **(velocity, searchVolume1, and searchVolume2)** whose values are to be changed such that: both `velocity` and `searchVolume2` are kept constant while `searchVolume1` is being changed from say `0.5, 2.4, 3.7, 4.6, 5.1, etc`. The procedure is repeated for next values of `velocity` (say: `10, 20, 30, 50, 70, etc`) and afterwards, `searchVolume2` is then also changed to different values `(say: 1,2,3,4,5,etc)`. There are three output variables **(t1, t2, and t3)** for each run, but these come in the form of a distribution.

Now, I have made my script as a function (`myMfile_sensitivity`) with the three outputs (`t1, t2, and t3`) and I have another script where I would need to call `myMfile_sensitivity`. However due to the nature of the complexity, I have decided to only alter `searchVolume1` and then use several computers for different `velocities` - after which I will repeat the runs for other values of `searchVolume2`.

I have re-edited my M-file to look this way:

```
Velocity = 10
searchVolume2 = 1
searchVolume1 = 0.5

% Pre-allocate storage for t1, t2, and t3
t1 = NaN(numel(X), kk)
t2 = NaN(numel(X), kk)
t3 = NaN(numel(X), kk)

For ii = 1: numel(X)    %where X is the no. of data points for the distribution
    Do….
    Do….
    While volume(ii,:) < searchVolume1(kk,:)
        Do…
        Do…
    End
    Do…
    Do…
    t1 = ….
    t2 = ….
End
```

In my new script, I have:

```
searchVolume1 = [0.5, 0.5, 2.4, 3.7, 4.6, 5.1]';
For kk = 1: numel(searchVolume1)
    [t1,t2,t3] = myMfile_sensitivity(searchVolume, kk)
End
```

The file runs but I end up seeing only the result for the last `searchVolume1`. How do I store all the outputs? Many thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You need to store your search volumes in an array and loop through it.

Comment: Thanks @Suever. I have now stored `searchVolume1` as a vector and i am looping through it (See the edited version above). Nevertheless, i see only the last result. Please how do i store all the outputs. I have tried various stuffs but it seems not to be working.